# How to escape sanitize strings like "\\r\\n "

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am recieving strings like:

```
"\\r\\n    "

"\\r  \\n"

"\\n  \\r  "
```

etc from a third party API.

I need to convert these to **empty string** before storing them into DB. How can I properly sanitize these in Node.js?

I can use `.replace` but I want to make sure to catch all edge cases.

Comment: Desired output please ?

Comment: empty string. I mentioned that in the question, but edited it bold now.

Comment: "_I want to make sure to catch all edge cases_" With edge cases you mean e.g. a different amount of spaces between the control characters? Perhaps some non-space characters between control characters? Partially or fully encoded characters with one or more of about twenty different character encoding systems ..? Is the question on the side of a bit broad already, or should I ask some more details ???

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
console.log("\\n  \\r  ".replace(/\\(n|r)\s*/g,""));
```

Comment: How about the "_edge cases_" ..?

Answer (score 1):

Considering you just want to replace the string with no values other than space character class or escaped space characters.

```js
let str = `"\\r\\n    "
"\\r  \\n"
"\\n  \\r  "
"\\n  \\r  Hello"
`

let op = str.replace(/^"(?:\\r|\\n|\s)*"?$/gm,'')

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ( i use `\\\\r` for slashesh as escape characters in JS to poperly generate your input string - which is shown console)

```js
let input="  \\\\r  \\\\n    ";
let output= input.replace(/\s*(\\\\r|\\\\n)\s*/g, '');

console.log(`input : "${input}"` );
console.log(`output : "${output}"`);
```